# WPF: why PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown EventTrigger works and MouseLeftButtonDown not?

Tags: wpf, eventtrigger

Please see this `EventTrigger`:

```
<ListView Name="ListViewFiles">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ListViewItemMouseLeftButtonDownCommand}"
                                   CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ListViewFiles, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ListView>
```

So i want to achieve 2 things:

1. I try to use `MouseLeftButtonDown`  instead of `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` but the event is not fired (why ??).
2. When the user click and hold the left button i want the event the fire after 500 `milliseconds` currently i am using `timer` - any other approach ?

Answer (score 2):

`MouseLeftButtonDown` probably isn't activating your trigger because of how WPF handles [`RoutedEvents`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/routed-events-overview). When a `RoutedEvent` gets marked "handled", WPF doesn't call any further event handlers for it.

`ListView` is almost definitely handling `MouseLeftButtonDown` internally, probably to change the selected item. Because `MouseLeftButtonDown` is a [bubbling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/routed-events-overview#routing-strategies) event, that means it gets marked as handled inside the `ListView` before it gets up the visual tree to your code, so it never arrives.

`PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown`, on the other hand, is a [tunneling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/routed-events-overview#routing-strategies) event, so it reaches your code *before* getting into the `ListView`.

As for the second part of your question, I don't know any better way to trigger code after some time than by using some sort of timer. Also, if you want to trigger it only after they've been *holding* the button for that amount of time, make sure you handle the `PreviewLeftMouseButtonUp` event to turn the timer off if they release the button before the time is up.